# How to serve a .php file locally?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

[This part of the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) says that I should be able to make a small, fake server to serve up some local `.php` files in a folder using

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

. But when I try that I get the following error:

```
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version are you using `php -v`?

Comment: @quanta `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4` Thanks, the perfect question.

Comment: _As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server._

Comment: The very first sentence of the documentation you linked to states: "As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server". I suggest you read more carefully next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using at least PHP 5.4 to do this.  If you're using a lower version, it won't work.